# Hiding main category title on a unique category archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, hook-woocommerce

I'm building a site with many different categories and need to simply remove the category titles on just **one** archive page:

http://redyearclients.co.uk/PandF/product-category/exterior-paving/paving-brands/

I've discovered methods of removing the title from all pages, but I need all other category pages to require the title, this page for example should stay as it looks now:

http://redyearclients.co.uk/PandF/product-category/exterior-paving/

Any help massively appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that purpose you will need to use **`woocommerce_page_title`** filter hook and the WooCommerce conditional **`is_product_category( 'category' )`** together.

Here is that code:

```
function removing_specific_category_page_title( $page_title ) {

    // Define HERE below your category slug to hide the corresponding title
    $category = 'my_category';

    if(is_product_category($category)) 
        $page_title = '';

    return $page_title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'removing_specific_category_page_title', 10, 1 );
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and fully functional.

Reference: [WooCommerce Conditional Tags - Product Category Pages](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#product-category-page)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, much appreciated. I dropped this into the functions file, with the correct slug, and no change!?

Comment: Ah this may be my error - the correct slug (paving-brands) is a first level sub category underneath "external-paving" - could you advise?

Comment: LoicTheAztec's answer is correct and functioning. You need to replace `$category = 'my_category';` with your slug, `$category = 'exterior-paving';` @LoicTheAztec obviously you're choice, but I'd stay away from posting your personal info in comments. SO has support for creating [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: LOL. thanks for the good laugh! Hope the OP will come back an accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry I think I've not asked the question correctly - it's the brand titles on the 'paving-brands' page that need removing (if you look you will see the brand name in beige boxes with the brand logos underneath - I just want the logos to show, no product title). Apologies and thanks!!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks so much for your patience and help, I've reposted the question (and hope I've worded it correctly this time!) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831556/hide-sub-category-titles-on-single-parent-sub-category-archive-page-woocommerce