# Removing some text in main title on product category archives pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, hook-woocommerce

On my WooCommerce web shop, I would like to remove **`Archive of :`** from main title on product category archives pages.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

I have tried to use this code based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768430/hiding-main-category-title-on-a-unique-category-archive-page/39769791#39769791), 
**But it doesn’t work**:

```
function changing_category_archive_page_title( $page_title ) {
    if(is_product_category()) {
        $title_arr = explode(' :', $page_title);
        $new_title = $title_arr[2];
        if(!empty($new_title)) echo $new_title;
        else echo $page_title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'changing_category_archive_page_title', 10, 1 );
```

How can I do to remove **`Archive of :`** from title?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seem that this **`'Archive of : '`** text is a customization of your theme, as it doesn't exist in classic WooCommerce. So in this case, it's normal that the code you are using doesn't work.

Without any guaranty, as I can't test it my self, you should try to use the [WordPress **`gettex()`** function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext), as I think that this is an addition to main title, as some themes use to do:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'removing_specific_text_in_categories_page_titles', 10, 2 );
function removing_specific_text_in_categories_page_titles( $translated_text, $untranslated_text )
{
    if ( 'Archive of :' == $untranslated_text ) {
        $translated_text = '';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.