# Hide sub category titles on single parent sub category archive page WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm building a WP ecommerce site with multiple categories & sub-categories and need to remove the sub-category titles on just **one** archive page.

All other category & sub category pages still require the sub category titles.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you okay with using css? Try this `.archive.term-paving-brands  category-name { display: none; }`. This should hide all category titles on paving brands page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - *Nov 2018*

> The easiest way for that purpose is to make a custom conditional function that you will use in the concerned related template **`content-product_cat.php`** where the this subcategory title is hooked.

**1) The conditional function**

Here is that code:

```
function is_parent_category( $subcategory_term, $parent_category_term_slug ) {
    $parent_term = get_term( $subcategory_term->parent, $subcategory_term->taxonomy );
    return $parent_term->slug == $parent_category_term_slug ? true : false;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**2) Overriding via your theme **`content-product_cat.php`** WooCommerce template.**

> If not done yet, inside your active child theme (or theme) create a **`woocommerce`** folder. Then copy from **`woocommerce`** plugin **`templates`** folder a file named **`content-product_cat.php`** inside the fresh created **`woocommerce`** folder in your active child theme (or theme).

The open/edit this copied **`content-product_cat.php`** template file.

Replace the following line:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );
```

By this:

```
if( ! is_parent_category( $category, 'exterior-paving' ) ) {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );
}
```

Save, you are done. Now as you wished, all the brand titles only on the 'paving-brands' archive page will be removed.

This code is tested and fully functional.

---

**ADDITION: Handling Multiple parent category slugs:**

To handle multiple parent category slugs use the following instead *(from an array of slugs)*:

```
function is_parent_category( $subcategory_term, $parent_category_term_slugs ) {
    $parent_term = get_term( $subcategory_term->parent, $subcategory_term->taxonomy );
    return in_array($parent_term->slug, $parent_category_term_slug ) ? true : false;
}
```

**USAGE** example:

```
// Reminder: $category is a WP_Term object
if ( is_parent_category( $category, array( 'clothing', 'posters' ) ) {
    // Do something (matching subcategory)
} else {
    // Do something else (no matching subcategory)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate the help.